# Print page number of a specific glossary entry (the description) defined with \newglossaryentry

Tags: glossaries

Is it possible to print the number of the page, where a specific glossary entry description (defined with `\newglossaryentry`) is printed (package `glossaries`)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{g:a}{name=A,description=\lipsum}
\newglossaryentry{g:b}{name=B,description=\lipsum}

\begin{document}

Glossary entry \gls{g:b} description is printed on page: X (I dont' know, how to print the page number).

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older version below, here is the linking and referring to the description page version:

I've found no way in the `glossaries-user` manual how to get the page reference where the description is placed. The idea is to use a slightly modified `glossarystyle`, here derived from `list` (which is effectively the standard) and adding a `\label{glo:page:##1}`, where `##1` expands to the glossary key.

The helper command `\descpageref{key}` will display the page where the description is typeset.

**Note**: This assumes unique keys, i.e. an equally named key from another `glossary` will lead to the same label.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[savenumberlist=true]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{g:a}{name=A,description=\lipsum}
\newglossaryentry{g:b}{name=B,description=\lipsum}

\let\origglspostdescription\glspostdescription


\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
\setglossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
\item[\glsentryitem{##1}\phantomsection\label{glo:page:##1}% Make a page label here  
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
  \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}
}

\newcommand{\descpageref}[2][glo:page:]{%
\pageref{#1#2}
}


\begin{document}


Glossary entry \gls{g:b} is printed on page: \descpageref{g:b} and the other one is on page \descpageref{g:a}

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=main,style=mystyle]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here's a variation of code I provided some days ago, defining a `\newglossary`, but that's not important.

It's possible to use, in conjunction with the `savenumberlist=true` option, the command `\glsdisplaynumberlist` which displays all occurences where some entry has been used. (The details of the glossary here aren't really important, they have nothing to do with the `\glsdisplaynumberlist` format)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[savenumberlist=true,nomain]{glossaries}


\newglossary[aul]{authordict}{aus}{aug}{Dictionary of Authors}

\makeglossaries


\glsaddkey{birthyear}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentrybirthyear}{\GLsentrybirthyear}{\glsbirthyear}{\Glsbirthyear}{\GLSbirthyear}
\glsaddkey{deathyear}{}{\glsentrydeathyear}{\GLsentrydeathyear}{\glsdeathyear}{\Glsdeathyear}{\GLSdeathyear}



\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
\setglossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
\item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}\myitemdelimiter}]
  \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}
}



\newglossaryentry{Maxwell}{%
name={James Clerk Maxwell},
birthyear={1831},
deathyear={1869},
description={English physicist},
type=authordict,
}

\newglossaryentry{Boltzmann}{%
  name={Ludwig Boltzmann},
  birthyear={1844},
  deathyear={1906},
  description={Austrian physicist},
  type=authordict
}

\newglossaryentry{Einstein}{%
  name={Albert Einstein},
  birthyear={1879},
  deathyear={1955},
  description={German physicist},
  type=authordict
}



\defglsentryfmt[authordict]{\glsentryname{\glslabel} (\glsentrybirthyear{\glslabel} -- \glsentrydeathyear{\glslabel}), \glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}


\begin{document}
    The Maxwell\footnote{\gls{Maxwell}}-
Boltzmann\footnote{\gls{Boltzmann}}
 model.


\clearpage
Einstein\footnote{\gls{Einstein}}
-Bose-Condensate versus \gls{Maxwell}



Entry \glsentryname{Maxwell} is on page(s) \glsdisplaynumberlist{Maxwell}
    \printglossary[type=authordict]


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** Here's the version for the O.P. MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[savenumberlist=true]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{g:a}{name=A,description=\lipsum}
\newglossaryentry{g:b}{name=B,description=\lipsum}

\begin{document}

Glossary entry \gls{g:b} is printed on page: \glsdisplaynumberlist{g:b} (i dunno how to print the page).

\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work for me. The page number it prints is 1 but it should be 4.

Comment: @MCH: Why 4? On page 4 is the glossary description. `\gls{g:b}` is used on page 1

Comment: Well, the whole point is to print the number of the page, where the glossary entry is printed.

Comment: @MCH: You mean the glossary description then. Sorry, your question is a little bit unclear then

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have phrased it 'description' then. I'll change the question.

Comment: @MCH: See my update at the top of my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I gladly accept your solution. There is just a minor thing: Could you make the hyperlink of the page number link to the page with this number instead of the start of the glossary?

Comment: @MCH: Done: `\phantomsection` was missing of course!

Comment: I have one additional question: Why did you put `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` around `\descpageref{g:b}`? --- Your code works without it as well!

Comment: @MCH: Yes, that's old code, when I had some command with `\@` for compilation tests. Of course it's not needed there